# Excel Formula to copy all cells data of one column in one cell by ignoring blank cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have data in Q column which is returned via another excel formula and I want excel formula to get o/p in R2 cell as shown below

Q column

1234567810 1111 8787

{Blank cell}

1234567811 1111 8787

{Blank cell}

{Blank cell}

{Blank cell}

{Blank cell}

{Blank cell}

{Blank cell}

1234567812 1111 8787

{Blank cell}

{Blank cell}

R2 cell

1234567810 1111 8787,1234567811 1111 8787,1234567812 1111 8787

I tried formula as `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,Q2:Q100)`, but its showing o/p as

> 1234567810 1111 8787,,1234567811 1111 8787,,,,,,,1234567812 1111 8787,,

So it's not ignoring blank cell values because blank cell values are returned via excel formula which is not actually making them blank but just showing them as blank

Comment: Filter out the `blank cells`. Copy the numbers that are left out and paste it in another sheet (where there are no filters). Now use `TEXTJOIN()` . This is simple and quick

Comment: How is this different from [your earlier question that was answered](https://superuser.com/questions/1288984/copy-all-cells-numeric-data-of-one-column-to-single-cell)?

Comment: Rocky,, check the solution I've posted.

Answer (score 0):

The answers in the comments, and the answers to the other question,
look pretty good. 
But here’s a simple answer
that doesn’t require the use of the `TEXTJOIN` function
(which doesn’t exist in Excel 2013 and below) or the use of VBA.

Set up a “helper column”; for example, Column `Z`. 
In `Z2`, enter

```
=IF(Q2<>"",Q2,"")
```

You might think that `=Q2` would be equivalent,
but if `Q2` is blank, then `=Q2` will give you a `0`;
see [Display Blank when Referencing Blank Cell in Excel](https://superuser.com/q/515932/150988). 
Alternatively, `=Q2&""` would probably be just as good.

In `Z3`, enter

```
=Z2&IF(AND(Z2<>"",Q3<>""),",","")&Q3
```

This gives you `Q2` and `Q3`
in the minimized joined (list without blanks) form that you want. 
If `Z2` (which equals `Q2`) and `Q3` are both non-blank, you get

```
Q2 & "," & Q3
```

i.e., `apple,banana`. 
If either `Q2` or `Q3` is blank, you get

```
Q2 & Q3
```

i.e., just plain `apple`, just plain `banana`, or blank.

Select `Z3` and drag/fill down to `Z100`. 
At each row `Zn`,
this adds `Qn` to the list so far,
inserting a comma only if `Qn` is not blank. 
(Here I have hidden Columns `S`-`Y`.)

[image: demo]

Then just set `R2` to `=Z100`. 
(Or use `=Z100&""`
if there’s a possibility that the entire list will be blank.)

Answer (score 0):

Showing all your information (especially those formulas in column Q) would be helpful.
I suspect your formula in Column Q is NOT returning a blank `""` but returning a space `" "` or some other non-printing character.

If it is returning a space, you have two options:

- Change the Column Q formula to return a blank and use `TEXTJOIN` as you are doing in your question
- Use the following formula which will effectively turn the spaces into empties:

---

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,TRIM(Q2:Q100))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd>
 + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do that properly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula.

A similar approach could be used for a different non-printing character.

Answer (score -1):

*If within the Data Range few blank Cells are available then you need to use the Formula like is below written.*

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,Q2,Q4,Q11)
```

Comment: Why not just say “Enter `1234567810 1111 8787,1234567811 1111 8787,1234567812 1111 8787` into `R2`”? Because the computer is supposed to do the work. With your answer, every time the data change, the user would have to manually look at the data, find the blank cells, and rewrite the formula accordingly. Did you notice that the OP is talking about having 99 cells? If the user has to do that much manual labor, what’s the point in having a computer?

Comment: @Scott, my answer is in context of OP, where the BOTTOM LINE was, while using TEXTJOIN, was getting error and was struggling with BLANK CELLS, so the prime requirement was how to IMPROVE the TEXTJOIN to get the correct results.

Comment: You suggested to use Helper Column and a different Formula, but OP is TEXTJOIN !!